# Level Creator for iPhone Game

Tags: iphone, macos, dictionary

I'm making an iPhone game that has several maps with graphics attached.  The graphics may allow the player to pass through them or block them.  Is there an application for OS X that will allow me to pass some of this work off to a designer without having to reinvent the wheel and develop a map creator.

Comment: I'd argue that this is more appropriate for Super User, given that you are asking about software packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if I get the gist I think this may help you out:
http://www.gamesalad.com/ <- Game editor/creator.

It doesn't offer much in the way of flexibility, but may be of some use to you.

Enjoi!

Comment: Game Salad is perfect for these type of tile based games.